# Python/PyQT QString won't insert into MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt4, qstring

I am trying to trying to retrieve some values from a user using a QLineEdit widget. When a QPushButton raises a clicked event, I want the text to be retrieved from all QLineEdit widgets and stored in a local MySQL databaase. However, when I try to use string substition in the insert statement, the values don't get substituted. Here's my sql statement:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (self.edi_IncidentID.text(), self.edi_OrganizationAffected.text(), self.edi_OrganizationContact.text(), self.edi_MediaType.text())
```

All of the self.edi_xxx variables are just QLineEdit widgets. When a button is pushed, the following is fired:

```
self.connect(btn_Submit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.submitForm)
```

All submit does is create a database object and write the values to the database. However, for debugging I print out the constructed SQL statement and this comes out:
INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("", "", "", "").

I have also tried using the str() function to convert a QString to a string but the same thing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)?

L

EDIT: Here is the complete code minus the imports:

```
class Database():
def __init__(self):
   self.db_host = "localhost"
   self.db_user = "***********"
   self.db_pass = "***********"
   self.db_name = "incidents"

def openConn(self):
   self.db = MySQLdb.connect(self.db_host, self.db_user, self.db_pass, self.db_name)

def closeConn(self):
   self.db.close()

def writeValues(self, sql):
   self.openConn()
   self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
   self.cursor.execute(sql)
   self.cursor.fetchone()
   self.closeConn()

class NewIncidentForm(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    self.setWindowTitle('New Incident')

    lbl_IncidentID = QtGui.QLabel('Incident ID:')
    lbl_MediaType = QtGui.QLabel('Media Type:')
    lbl_OrganizationAffected = QtGui.QLabel('Organization Affected:')
    lbl_OrganizationContact = QtGui.QLabel('Organization Point of Contact: ')

    self.edi_IncidentID = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.edi_MediaType = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.edi_OrganizationAffected = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.edi_OrganizationContact = QtGui.QLineEdit()


    btn_Submit = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit')

    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    grid.setSpacing(10)

    grid.addWidget(lbl_IncidentID, 1, 0)
    grid.addWidget(self.edi_IncidentID, 1, 1)

    grid.addWidget(lbl_MediaType, 3, 0)
    grid.addWidget(self.edi_MediaType, 3, 1)

    grid.addWidget(lbl_OrganizationAffected, 4, 0)
    grid.addWidget(self.edi_OrganizationAffected, 4, 1)

    grid.addWidget(lbl_OrganizationContact, 5, 0)
    grid.addWidget(self.edi_OrganizationContact, 5, 1)

    grid.addWidget(btn_Submit, 15, 0)

    self.sql = 'INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (self.edi_IncidentID.text(), self.edi_OrganizationAffected.text(), self.edi_OrganizationContact.text(), self.edi_MediaType.text())
    self.connect(btn_Submit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.submitForm)        

    self.setLayout(grid)
    self.resize(350, 300)

def submitForm(self):
    db = Database()
    db.writeValues(self.sql)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = NewIncidentForm()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you post more code? So far it can be everything and nothing. By the way if I were you I would change the code since you can have a SQL injection attack to the db by getting as input: 

sql = 'INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (
"", "","", ");DELETE jobs;")

Comment: added the rest of the code.. and it would be vulnerable to SQL injection if it could actually write something to the database:P

Answer (score 1):

:D
QString have `__str__` functions so try this:

```
self.sql = 'INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (''.join(self.edi_IncidentID.text()), ''.join(self.edi_OrganizationAffected.text()), ''.join(self.edi_OrganizationContact.text()), ''.join(self.edi_MediaType.text()))
```

added `''.join()`

Or QString have toUtf8()

so change `self.edi_IncidentIS.text()` to:

```
self.edi_IncidentIS.text().toUtf8()
```

Whole instruction:

```
self.sql = 'INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (self.edi_IncidentID.text().toUtf8(), self.edi_OrganizationAffected.text().toUtf8(), self.edi_OrganizationContact.text().toUtf8(), self.edi_MediaType.text().toUtf8())
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is very simple:

self.sql should be in 
def submitForm(self):

not in 
def **init**(self, parent=None):

because otherweise it's void!

Answer (score 1):

the other part that is missing for the program is the commit() function to have data stored or autocommit(true) at the begging  of the script

```
def closeConn(self):
self.db.close()
self.db.commit()

def submitForm(self):
db = Database()
self.sql = 'INSERT INTO jobs (incident_id, organization, organization_poc, media_type) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (self.edi_IncidentID.text(), self.edi_OrganizationAffected.text(), self.edi_OrganizationContact.text(), self.edi_MediaType.text())      
db.writeValues(self.sql)
```