# Insert data from lineEdit into mysql is blank in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I want to get data from lineEdit ,show it in tablewidget and insert it into mysql.
But it's strange tablewidget is blank ,nothing in Item and mysql don't change.I have saw [**Python/PyQT QString won't insert into MySQL database**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569161/python-pyqt-qstring-wont-insert-into-mysql-database). But I failed.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui,QtSql
import sys
from test2 import Ui_MainWindow 
#I use Qt designer to do the UI

class StartQt4(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")  #select database type
        self.db.setHostName("localhost")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("test")   
        self.db.setUserName("root")
        self.db.setPassword("")
        if (self.db.open()):
            self.showdata()
        else:
            print "failed"
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add)

    def add(self):
        name0 = str(self.lineEdit.text())    
        name1 = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        name2 = str(self.lineEdit_3.text())
        print type(name0)
        self.query=QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.db)
        self.query.exec_("insert into qiu (name0,nam1,name2) value ('%s','%s','%s')" %(''.join(name0),''.join(name1),''.join(name2)))
        self.query.exec_("commit")
        lastrow=self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(lastrow)
        self.showdata()    

    def  showdata(self):
        query=QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.db)
        query.exec_("select * from qiu")
        for i in range(0,self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            query.next()
            name0 = query.value(0).toString()
            name1 = query.value(1).toString()
            name2 = query.value(2).toString()
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name0))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name1))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQt4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Without your `test2` module we have no chance to reproduce an error. 
You have an typo at the insert command, "nam1" (should be "name1"), too. Stopped looking more into this at this point.

Comment: But this statement is right. `q.exec_("insert into qiu (name0,name1,name2) value ('%s','%s','%s')" %('1','2','3'))`.And how can I add `test2` module?